# Reading a file encoded with AMF3

Tags: c#, file, serialization

I'm trying to read in a .dat file encoded in AMF3 with C#. I'm looking for a solution still yesterday.

I've first tried to find how AMF3 encoding works. I was using the [Adobe document dealing with AMF3 encoding](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/amf/pdf/amf-file-format-spec.pdf). But it doesn't work (I don't know how I should do to treat bit by bit).

Then I've tried to read the AMFNet code, but the problem is that it only supports AMF0 and I want AMF3.

Then I've downloaded FluorineFx but I've understood that it's only for server communication.

Is there anyone who knows a solution ?

Thank you,

Veriditas.

Comment: Asking for an off-site solution is off topic. A better approach would be to provide the details of why your first attempt did not work, and ask a specific question about it ("I don't know how I should do to treat bit by bit").

Comment: First, I don't know what I should do for integer. If I must read 4 bytes and get only the 29 first bits or to read only 29 first bits. Because it has a consequence in next datas read I think. However, I don't know how I can get the first bit for the flag and the 28 others for the value. It's just an example for integer, I have coped with other issues of reading bit by bit.

Comment: Please edit your post to include what you have tried so far (code examples), and this information.